# differentiate among multiple webclient results

Tags: c#, .net, webclient

There is a List.

I want to download each url via webclient.DownloadStringAsync

the problem I encounter is:
how do I know which e.Result corresponds to what url ?

```
public class ressource{
public string url { get; set; }
public string result  { get; set; }
}

List<ressource> urlist = new List<ressource>();
urlist.Add(new ressource(){url="blabla", result=string.empty});
....etc

var wc= new WebClient();
foreach(var item in urlist)
{
wc.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadStringCompleted);
    wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(item.url, UriKind.Absolute));
}

 void wc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
 {
 urlist[?].result = e.Result; 
 }
```

I feel completely stuck.
Thanks for your ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the problem I encounter is: how do I know which e.Result corresponds to what url ?

There are various different options for this:

**UserState**

You *can* pass in a second argument to `DownloadStringAsync`, which is then available via [`DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs.UserState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.asynccompletedeventargs.userstate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). For example:

```
// In your loop....
var wc = new WebClient();
wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(item.url, UriKind.Absolute), item);

void wc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var item = (ressource) e.UserState;
    item.result = e.Result;
}
```

**Multiple WebClients**

You can create a new `WebClient` for each iteration of the loop, and attach a different event handler to it. A lambda expression is useful here:

```
// Note: this is broken in C# 3 and 4 due to the capture semantics of foreach.
// It should be fine in C# 5 though.
foreach(var item in urlist)
{
    var wc = new WebClient();
    wc.DownloadStringCompleted += (sender, args) => item.result = args.Result;
    wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(item.url, UriKind.Absolute));
}
```

**DownloadStringTaskAsync**

You could [`DownloadStringTaskAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194294%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead, so that each call returns a `Task<string>`. You could keep a collection of these - one for each element in `urlist` - and know which is which that way.

Alternatively, you could just fetch all the results synchronously, but I suspect you don't want to do that.

**Additional information**

Unfortunately, `WebClient` doesn't support multiple concurrent connections, so with *all* the options above you should create a new `WebClient` per iteration anyway.

Comment: ok, let's say I put new webclient inside foreach loop. I still don't see how could I create event hnd with different names automatically. this seems very complicated, isn't it a different approach maybe?

Comment: @acadea: I've edited my answer with various options.

Comment: UserState is exactly what I was looking for. it's worth mentioning though that webclient should be created inside the loop even when using UserState because webclient could not have concurrent connections. You've made my day!

Comment: @acadea: Interesting - I wasn't even aware of the limitation there. Will edit!

Comment: yes, there are dozen of questions about this on SO: WebClient does not support concurrent I/O operations. I could use wc.isBusy to sequence the request thus losing "the concurrent feature" but still having the UI responsive

Comment: Would copying `item` to a local variable inside the `foreach` help with C# 4 capture semantics?

Comment: @Boris: Yup. I just didn't want to get distracted by that in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative, and the one I prefer, is to use Microsoft's Reactive Framework (Rx). It handles all the background threading for you, similar to the TPL, but often easier.

Here's how I would do it:

```
var query =
    from x in urlist.ToObservable()
    from result in Observable.Using(
        () => new WebClient(),
        wc => Observable.Start(() => wc.DownloadString(x.url)))
    select new
    {
        x.url,
        result
    };
```

Now to get the results back into the original `urlist`.

```
var lookup = urlist.ToDictionary(x => x.url);

query.Subscribe(x =>
{
    lookup[x.url].result = x.result;
});
```

Simple as that.